# App crashing using QuickBlox video chat module

Tags: quickblox

I am using quickblox video chat module, app works fine when test devices are on same internet connection, but crashes when test devices are on different internet connections, it is crashed when [QBTURNClient processReceivedData:] is called, please help me in this regard!